# How to search for unjoined tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

How to get the table names of all unjoined tables (Which are not connected using a foreign key to another table). Using SQL Server?

Below is the table structure. The query should only return `Table4` since it is not joined to any table using any constraint.

Table Structure : [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/harshamw/zqa6app9/)

Comment: "Unjoined tables" does not make sense. Anyway, any two tables can be joined. You don't need a FK between them. PS Please use text not images whenever you can. Like here for your whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables which doesn't have foreign keys:

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [type] = 'U' AND object_id NOT IN (
    SELECT f.parent_object_id
    FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
       ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to find which tables do not have any foreign keys defined on them (but may be referenced by other keys):

```
    select t.[name] from sys.tables t
    left join sys.foreign_keys k on t.object_id = k.parent_object_id
    where k.object_id is null
```

Query to find which tables are not referenced by any key:

```
select t.[name] from sys.tables t
left join sys.foreign_keys k on t.object_id = k.referenced_object_id
where k.object_id is null
```

Comment: Hi @Pawel : I just ran there queries. In my DB there are no isolated tables. But both the queries returned values. The query should not return values according to this scenario. I added all the tables in the query designer, all the tables are interconnected to each other. I checked it one by one.